# google cloud machine learning error

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

pleas help me
i cannot solve this

ERROR: (gcloud.beta.ml.models.versions.create) FAILED_PRECONDITION: Field: version.deployment_uri Error: The model directory gs://valued-aquifer-164405-ml/mnist_deployable_garu_20170413_150711/model/ is expected to contain exactly one of the following: the 'export.meta' file, or 'saved_model.pb' file or 'saved_model.pbtxt' file.Please make sure one of these files exists and you have read access to it.

Answer (score 0):

I am new to Google Cloud. I have also got the same kind of issue. When I was trying to create version for model. I have resolved it.

you need to do two steps:

- Export model --> it will give you saved_model.pbtxt, I am using tensorflow so I have used export_savedmodel()
- Upload saved_model.pbtxt & variables folder to storage
  and try

Comment: Hi - Is there an example you can point me to? I'm trying to figure out how to do this so I can use my tensorflow model with Google Cloud ML

Answer (score 0):

This command has since been updated to `gcloud ml-engine versions create`.

It is recommended to run `gcloud components update` to install the latest GCloud, then follow the [new instructions](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/how-tos/deploying-models) for deploying your own models to Cloud ML Engine.

- Note: If you experience issues with GCloud in the future, it is recommended to report the issue in a [Public Issue Tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers).