# Google Cloud Machine Learning API: error directory is expected to contain exactly one of: [saved_model.pb, saved_model.pbtxt]

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-ml

I've seen this thread but it does not help. [google cloud machine learning error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43384964/google-cloud-machine-learning-error)

I call the ML engine API [`versions.create` endpoint](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/reference/rest/v1/projects.models.versions/create), authenticated with a service account, and I get this error
`directory is expected to contain exactly one of: [saved_model.pb, saved_model.pbtxt]`

But the directory referenced in `deploymentUri` actually contains only `saved_model.pb` so I don't understand why I get this error...

my code:

```
body = {
        u"name": version_name,
        u"description": description,
        u"runtimeVersion": current_default_version.get(u"runtimeVersion"),
        u"framework": current_default_version.get(u"framework"),
        u"pythonVersion": current_default_version.get(u"pythonVersion"),
        u"deploymentUri": deployment_uri
 }
 request = ml_client.projects().models().versions().create(parent=get_query_name(model_name), body=body)
 operation = request.execute()
```

body

```
{
    'name': 'test',
    'runtimeVersion': '1.0',
    'pythonVersion': '2.7',
    'framework': 'TENSORFLOW',
    'deploymentUri': 'gs://XXX/keras/YYY/1/export'
}
```

Please note:
- My ML service account has admin right on the Cloud Storage bucket
- The service account I use for the service account has owner rights on the ML models

Answer (score 0):

Could you check that your deploymentUri is correct? Usually, the export directory contains a subdirectory whose name is a timestamp

Comment: Nope the uri was right. It was something to do with the permission on my bucket for my service account. I didn't find the "best" permission to give, but giving all the "read" permissions solved the problem

Comment: Since you managed to fix it, could you post this as an answer and accept it?